# Save a numpy ndarray (1, 160, 160) into a grayscale image

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I have a (5200, 1, 160, 160) array that I could iterate.
How can I save (1, 160, 160) array into grayscale image?

Comment: `for i,a in enumerate(your_array): cv2.imwrite(f'file_{i}.png', a[0])`.

Comment: @QuangHoang is the array the one with 5200 batches or just (1, 160, 160)?
Wrong for me. if I use (5200, 1, 160, 160) as 'your_array', I get a black image. if i use (1, 160, 160) as the image, I get nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose `gray` has shape (1, 160, 160) which you want to save in grayscale, then you can do this:

```
cv2.imwrite('gray_image.png', gray[0])
```

I suppose you know how to iterate thrpugh the main array. If this does not solve your question let me know.